# C# JavaScriptSerializer creates invalid json

Tags: c#, json

I tried to convert an anonymous object into a JSON object today but when I parse the result of the conversion it says the JSON is invalid. I am clueless why it does that. any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

```
var s = new
{
    displayName = "ppplll",
        description = "Self help community for library",
        groupTypes = new[] { "Unified" },
        mailEnabled = true,
        mail = "emali@abc.com",
        mailNickname = "library",
        securityEnabled = false
};
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(s);
```

The json that gets created:

```
"{\"displayName\":\"ppplll\",\"description\":\"Self help community for library\",\"groupTypes\":[\"Unified\"],\"mailEnabled\":true,\"mail\":\"email@abc.com\",\"mailNickname\":\"library\",\"securityEnabled\":false}"
```

Comment: Parse how? Who says that JSON is invalid? What json is produced?

Comment: parsed it at: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ . Also included the Json in the post.

Comment: So that json is valid. Question remains: who says that it's invalid?

Comment: apparently after using @ciprian's answer worked. it is just a formatting difference between C# and the parsers i guess.

Comment: Well that string you probably got from debug view in Visual Studio. It displayed there as string literal, so all special characters (like quotes) are escaped with "\". The real string does not contain those slashes, only debug view (and even there you can click on dropdown button and choose "Text View" or "JSON view" to see plain text).

Comment: @Evk thanks for your explanation it makes a little bit more sense to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace \" with " and then use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. The json is valid.

Comment: that worked. Could you please elaborate why C# uses the \" ? thanks for the info.

Comment: That string is actually a literal from debug. " marks the beginning/end of a string. When " character is actually part of the string (as is the case with json), it needs to be escaped using \. If you like to see the string without escaped ", use "Text visualizer".